# Using Yii's CActiveRecord onBeforeDelete

Tags: events, activerecord, yii

I'm trying to attach some listeners to a `CActiveRecord`'s onBeforeDelete, this I'm doing as follows:

```
<?php
class SomeModule extends CWebModule
{
    public function init()
    {
        Submission::model()->onBeforeDelete = array($this, 'cleanUpFiles');
    }

    public function cleanUpFiles ($event) {
        var_dump('Well... Hi there, being deleted are we?');
    }
}
?>
```

Sadly, this does not have any effect on `Submission`'s `delete()`. Though, when replacing `onBeforeDelete` with `onBeforeFind`, it seems to react seamlessly on the find methods. I'm having the feeling that the onBeforeDelete should be applied to an instance of `Submission` and not on it's singleton model, is that feeling correct? If I'm correct, is there any other way to attach my event listener in global on every `Submission`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right you have to  apply onBeforeDelete  to an instance of Submission

Comment: And is there no way to do this in a global way? I would like to listen to **all** instance deletions.

Comment: Rather you could have achieved the desired task using the afterDelete() function which is called automatically when you have called delete()

Comment: Well, yeah, I could, but I would like to keep my model clean of all the add-on modules, these could (in my case) be removed and / or deleted at any time. When using events, I won't need to be worrying about the module being there or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this with a little bit of improvisation, I've overwritten the `Submission`'s function `beforeDelete()` as follows:

```
<?php
protected function beforeDelete() {
    foreach (Submission::model()->onBeforeDelete as $key => $value) {
        $this->onBeforeDelete = $value;
    }
    return parent::beforeDelete();
}
?>
```

Now, when delete is called, the `beforeDelete()` will rip out the onBeforeDelete from the singleton model and assign it to it's own instance. Now, the callbacks are being triggered.